# Binary Search in Python. Searching for elements containing a specific phrase / letter

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search

You know how in SQL you can use the LIKE query to find the elements in a database that contain a certain phrase is it possible to do that in python with an array using a binary search

Eg array = [128 to 300, 400, 500 , 550 to 600]

Would it be possible to use a binary search to search for the elements containing to in the array above.

In python

Ive coded a normal binary search by following a tutorial but that is not allowing me to find it

Comment: That "array = ..." isn't valid Python.

Comment: LIKE in SQL works on strings.  You should provide an example that contains strings.  Also, binary search relies on data being sorted and needs the search value to be exact or a prefix.  Searches using LIKE that don't place the wildcard at the end cannot use binary search on a normal ascending index.  Technically a reversed index could be used for suffix searches but database don't usually set that up by default.

Comment: @AlainT. You can easily do binary search with suffixes or completely different things. Even Python's `bisect` makes that convenient now, thanks to the `key` parameter.

Comment: You're still dependent on the order though.  Which is what I meant by a reversed index (and I was referring to SQL not Python).

Answer (score -2):

Using the `bisect` module:

```
>>> array = ["128 to 300", "400", "500", "550 to 600"]
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_left(array, "400")
1
>>> array[1]
'400'
```

Note that binary search requires the elements of the list to be in sorted order -- in this case the elements (which are strings) do in fact happen to be in sorted order, but this is lexicographic ordering, *not* numeric, so it may not actually be generalizable to your real use case if the intent is to have a list of numeric ranges.

A `range` object, which is the usual way to represent a numeric range, does not have a comparison operator (meaning a list of ranges can't be sorted or binary-searched), since ranges can overlap such that one is both less than and greater than the other at its different ends.  If you want to do a binary search of a list of ranges, you will need to think about how to handle the possibility of overlaps and implement a comparison function that accounts for that in an appropriate way.